# how can i read a tfrecord file from zip file in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

I need to zip tfrecord files for decreasing size of these files and I want to use these zip file for reading tfrecord files in tensorflow without extraction. I know that I can use zipfile library in python for reading zip files but i don't know how can I read a tfrecord file from a zip file. 
thanks!